# Installing Theano in Winpython using tutorial from deeplearning.net

Tags: python, spyder, theano

I'm trying to install Theano in my Windows Server 2008 OS(64-bit) and I'm following the tutorial given in

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#install-windows

I followed the "Winpython" approach and

have reached this step

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#configuring-theano

As Instructed I executed the command

`python setup.py develop`

The tutorial said "this step will add the `Theano` directory to you `PYTHON_PATH` environment variable"

However after executing the code when I try to import theano, it shows that the module cannot be found.

If I directly copy the `theano` directory into the `site-package` folder of my `winpython` directory , I get a lot of jumbled messages and errors (over 100 lines) In my ipython console.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Is there a better tutorial that I can follow ?